# How to write into the same CSV file with FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter

I have a simple question that I could not figure out how to solve. I run an algorithm on different instances, and want to output the results into the same Excel file.

As an toy example, I wrote the following code, but it does not work properly.

```
String DATADIR = "C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/";
for(int i =0; i<=2 ; i++){          
  File f = new File(DATADIR+ "myFile.csv"); // I first check if the file exists
  FileWriter mainWriter = null; // here there is a problem
    if(!f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { // If not, then I create the file
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(DATADIR+ "myFile.csv", true);
    mainWriter = writer; // I copy the file for the next iterations
    writer.write("This is my first line \n"); 
    writer.close();
    }else { //if file exists, then continue writing
        mainWriter.write(i+ "\n"); // as an trivial example, write the iterator
        mainWriter.close();
    }
```

There are several issues obviously, but I receive the null point exception. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint / direction.

Comment: Why are you closing `writer` mid loop and complicate your code by using two `FileWriter`s?

Comment: @jrook So If I am not mistaken, when using ```FileWriter```, if you do not close the file, the excel file is not updated.

Comment: Yes, but you can close it after you have done all your writing and appending. Closing it midway could cause the issue you are seeing

Comment: your `mainWriter` is null. So if the program branches into `else` clause, it will see a null value and throw NPE. Better to initialize your writer and keep it open during the write and close it afterwards.

Comment: @jrook You're right. Thanks for the recommendation. What you said makes much more sense than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting null pointer exception because,if file is available then go to else condition and there id no initialization for filewriter.you don't need to  use two writer.here i am posting some code let me know if it helps.

```
String DATADIR = "C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            File tmpDir = new File(DATADIR+" myFile.csv");
            if (!tmpDir.exists() && !tmpDir.isDirectory()){ //checking file availability
                tmpDir.createNewFile(); //create new file
            }
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(DATADIR+ "myFile.csv", true); //as mentioned if not available then create new file so here always available file
            if (i==0){
               writer.write("This is my first line \n"); //writing first line
                     }
            else {
                writer.write(i+ "\n"); //then appends all other data.
            }
            writer.close();

        }
```